# Avoid Adding Event Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mootools

I am dynamically adding events using `addEvent("keydown", function() {});` to an element. My problem is that there are times when this code gets run on the same element twice or more. The behavior becomes clunky as the function registered for that event runs a couple of times.

Is there a way for me to run the code above only once on an element? Maybe check if the event has already been added before?

Comment: Is this question related to the last one? are you receiving multiple answers from the Autocomplete/ajax plugin?

Comment: @Sergio Yes this is related. I have a function where the code mentioned above is located. When the page loads, that function gets called which adds an event listener to all inputs which has a certain class. On that page, the user has the ability to create more inputs after which I call the same function to add the same event. The problem now is that the previously added event doesn't get overridden, instead it is duplicated, which is why I get so many AJAX requests being done by the Autocompleter.

Comment: @Sergio also, I don't blame the Autocompleter for sending multiple answers. Since I know that I am making the same AJAX request multiple times, it's natural for the plugin to reply with the same results for the same number of times I made the request to get those results.

Comment: instead of using addEventListener we can use onclick as well. For ex:                                             document.getElementsByClassName('claNamess').onclick = (event) => {
      callback(event)
 }                                                                                                                                                       To know more about it follow this article: https://medium.com/dailyjs/whats-the-difference-between-event-handlers-addeventlistener-in-js-963431f05c34

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either don't use a new function each time, or use a class or something to tell you you've added it.

#### Not using a new function each time

MooTools' `addEvent` is a fairly thin wrapper on `addEventListener`/`attachEvent`, which won't add the same function twice. So if you ensure you're using the same function, you can call `addEvent` again without it doing anything:

```
// Somewhere it's created **once**
function keyDownHandler() {
    // ....
}
```

then:

```
element.addEvent("keydown", keyDownHandler);    // Adds it only if not there
```

**Live Example:**

```js
addIt();
addIt();

function addIt() {
  $("foo").addEvent("click", handler);
}

function handler() {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = new Date();
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
```

#### Remembering you've added it:

```
if (!element.hasClass("keydown-handler")) {
    element.addClass("keydown-handler").addEvent("keydown", function() { /*...*/});
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
addIt();
addIt();

function addIt() {
  var element = $("foo");
  if (!element.hasClass("click-handler")) {
    element.addClass("click-handler").addEvent(
      "click",
      function() {
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerHTML = new Date();
        document.body.appendChild(p);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.5.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your first suggestion worked. Have not tried your second approach but it looks like it would work as well for my case.

Comment: just use a closure because this implies the handler is available to all interested scopes, you don't want globals... he may fail to organise it properly. there is another way to check if there is a handler in MooTools in particular - did that some 4-5 yrs ago. still works. http://jsfiddle.net/vkx2ykvu/1/ - can be extended to support `hasEvent('click', myFenExactly)`

Comment: @DimitarChristoff: I didn't (and wouldn't) suggest globals. I'm assuming the above is contained in something, it usually is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your problem is not where or when to add event handler, but how to add. It is possible to delegate events to parent element. For example, this is a classic way of adding an event handler directly to the target element.

```
new Element( 'p', { 'text': 'Some Text' } ).inject( $( 'container' ) );

$$( '#container p' ).addEvent( 'click', function() {
    console.log( this );            
});

new Element( 'p', { 'text': 'Some Text' } ).inject( $( 'container' ) );
```

And, of course, only the first paragraph has click event.

And below is an example of event delegation.

```
$( 'container' ).addEvent( 'click:relay(p)', function() {
    console.log( this );            
});             

$( 'container' ).adopt([
    new Element( 'p', { 'text': 'Some Text' } ),
    new Element( 'p', { 'text': 'Some Text' } )
]);
```

Since event listener is assigned to a parent for all of its children, all paragraphs will have the click event, no matter when and where they are created. It is very useful when you are adding elements into the page dynamically.

I do not know how much this helps, but it's good to know.

[**Element.Delegation**](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Element/Element.Delegation)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem initiating js class instance which should add event, so using 'document.addEventListener' made situation when code attached to listeners called multiple time after creating instances of the same class. I resolved it by static function added into class Helper:

```
'use strict';
export default class Helper {
    //avoid multiple reactions for reinited objects which uses document attached events
    static events = [];
    static addSingleEventListener(event_name, instance, callback) {

        if (!instance.instance_key) {
            console.error(`Instance ${instance.constructor.name} not has instance_key field!`);
            return;
        }

        if (!Helper.events[instance.instance_key]) {
            Helper.events[instance.instance_key] = [];
        }

        if (!Helper.events[instance.instance_key][event_name]) {
            Helper.events[instance.instance_key][event_name] = callback.bind(instance);
            document.addEventListener(event_name, e => Helper.events[instance.instance_key][event_name](e));
        } else {
            Helper.events[instance.instance_key][event_name] = callback.bind(instance);
        }
    }

}
```

Using:

```
'use strict';
import Helper from './helper.js';

//16-11-2022
export default class Color {
    constructor(panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
        this.instance_key = 'woof-sd-color';//!! for attaching document events


        Helper.addSingleEventListener('woof_sd_childs_term_color', this, e => this.reload(parseInt(e.detail.id)));
    }
}
```

Make your attention on **this.instance_key** - this should be defined and unique!

Answer (score 0):

I will share what I did to solve my issues,

I had a code like this:

```
function mouseoverHandler(ele) {
    dosomething(ele);
}

ele.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {mouseoverHandler(ele)});
```

I changed it to something like this:

```
function mouseoverHandler() {
    dosomething(this);
}

ele.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseoverHandler);
```

I guess its essentially same thing as what @t-j-crowder means by do not use `new`, I wasn't using new but I was wrapping the logic in an arrow function.